# Activity into another Activity doesn't work

Tags: android

I try to invoke another activity into MainActivity. I create each class for activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

And also sub Activity :

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, "key");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        androidGesturesManager = new AndroidGesturesManager(this);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }
```

And then I add this into layout xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the map doesn't show.

I'm new to Android, so it's probably a simple problem but I have not found the answer, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: That's not how activities work. You can only have one Activity on screen at a time. What you need is to have a fragment hosted inside your MainActiivty. Start here https://www.raywenderlich.com/1364094-android-fragments-tutorial-an-introduction-with-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

When you do  what it means is that the layout is attached to that very activity.

You will need to do this

```
        androidGesturesManager = new AndroidGesturesManager(this);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

inside the activity with the layout carrying the  tag.